# Setting page.driver.block_unknown_urls in Cucumber?

Tags: cucumber, capybara, capybara-webkit

I am using cucumber and I keep getting this warning

```
Request to unknown URL: http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro
To block requests to unknown URLs:
  page.driver.block_unknown_urls
To allow just this URL:
  page.driver.allow_url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro")
To allow requests to URLs from this host:
  page.driver.allow_url("fonts.googleapis.com")
```

I understand I need to set the page.driver.block_unknown_urls configurations but I am not sure where to do this in cucumber.

Could someone please explain where I should set this configuration in cucumber

Comment: If the error is coming from Cucumber, what does this question have to do with CSS, Sass, or Webkit?

Comment: its being caused by a call to a remote font in the css

Comment: Unless your question requires someone with expertise in a specific language (CSS, Sass, etc.), don't tag your question with it.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll bear that in mind in future

Comment: you need to add a tag for whichever driver you're using - either capybara-webkit or poltergeist -- capybara doesn't support url black/whitelists natively currently

Comment: I did add one for Webkit but it was removed